# Shortcut for record profiler in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, browser, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

Is there any way to start the profiler without focusing the mouse pointer at the dev-tool window ?

I tried <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> , but it didn't work

Here is my Google Chrome version : **Version 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit)**

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hack. This only works on Chrome 61 and later. 61 is currently in Beta. It should hit Stable by mid-September 2017. Check `chrome://version` to see what version you're running.

So, there's no dedicated shortcut for starting the profiler without focusing the viewport. But you can start the profiler when focus is on the viewport, without using your mouse.

1. Go to the **Memory** panel.
2. Put focus in your viewport.
3. Press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (that's the backtick character, to the left of the <kbd>1</kbd> key on QWERTY keyboards). If you've got the **Console** panel open, focus goes back to that. If you're on a different panel, focus goes to the **Console** drawer. If the drawer is closed, DevTools opens it first and then puts focus on it.
4. Now, press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (Windows, Linux) to start / stop the profiler.

The downside is that focus is now back in DevTools. I'm not sure if there's a way to return focus back to the viewport.